# Why do java.util.calendar object's values change after a call to get(int)

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to debug a problem in some legacy code.

I have narrowed the problem to the following method:

```
public String formatDateTimeFromCalendar (Calendar cal){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String hr = ""+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        sb.append(String.format("%02d", hr)); 
        sb.append(":");
        sb.append(String.format("%02d", cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
        sb.append( " on ");
        sb.append(String.format("%02d", cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
        sb.append( "/");
        sb.append(String.format("%02d", cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));
        sb.append( "/");
        sb.append( cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Debugging
Line 2 the `cal` parameter is a future date. (2015-01-06T00:00:00.000Z)

After execution of line 3 with the first `cal.get(` the `cal` param's values have changed (to 2014-12-12T00:00:00.000Z)

Why/how could this be?

Here is where the calendar is being created:

```
Calendar startDateAndTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        startDateAndTime.setTime(response.getStartDate().toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
        startDateAndTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, response.getStartTime().getHour());
        startDateAndTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, response.getStartTime().getMinute());
        startDateAndTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, response.getStartTime().getSecond());
        startDateAndTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, response.getStartTime().getMillisecond());
```

`response.getStartDate()` returns an `XMLGregorianCalendar`

Comment: is the passed-in calendar object used in more than one thread?

Comment: Notice you're using a `String` as argument in `%02d` format, which requires an integer normally.

Comment: No threads explicitly. Its part of a web app.

Comment: normally an int? - That was my quick modification of the line to extract out the get to add a break point to it.

Comment: web apps are inherently multi-threaded. So it would certainly depend on where you get the Calendar object from. Can you show where the Calender is created/fetched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because calls of `get` normalize the `Calendar` in lenient mode, and validate it in strict mode:

> returns the value of the given calendar field. In lenient mode, all calendar fields are normalized. In non-lenient mode, all calendar fields are validated and this method throws an exception if any calendar fields have out-of-range values. The normalization and validation are handled by the `complete()` method, which process is calendar system dependent.

It looks like your `Calendar` object is in lenient mode, hence the normalization is performed. Normalization is dependent on the calendar instance.

Comment: but 2015-01-06 is perfectly valid, how could this normalize to 2014-12-12?

Comment: @geert3 When you use set() method for example, it enforces fields recomputation on subsequent get().

Comment: @mkrakhin ok makes sense. The debugger is showing the "old" value while actually it was already changed at that point.

Comment: @geert3 not sure about debugger behavior in this case.

Comment: I have just checked and the calendar is in lenient mode. However complete() is a protected method. Are you saying that the values that it was created with are invalid?

Comment: The error was due to an incorrect value in millisecond. The value being set was -2147483648. So as you say the calendar was lenient and being parsed as strict. This unfortunatley hid the error. I figured it out by setting startDateAndTime.setLenient(false); This caused an error to be thrown which allowed me to figure out the problem

Answer (score 2):

This is source code of java.util.Calendar for get() method.

```
public int get(int field)
    {
        complete();
        return internalGet(field);
    }
```

complete() method checks if all fields were set in instance and could normalize date and time.
This is default implementation of complete() method

```
protected void complete()
{
    if (!isTimeSet)
        updateTime();
    if (!areFieldsSet || !areAllFieldsSet) {
        computeFields(); // fills in unset fields
        areAllFieldsSet = areFieldsSet = true;
    }
}
```

But you shouldn't think that your fields are necessary invalid. This could happen if you manually edited calendar instance calling set() method, it unconditionally sets isTimeSet and areFieldsSet to false enforcing recomputation on subsequent obtaining of data.

Comment: The calendar object is edited with the .set method. I'll double check the values are correct.

Comment: @MarkW check update to my answer and last comment of geert3 in second answer.